# Using timer within android activity to display slideshow

Tags: java, android, timer

I have an android activity in which I display a slideshow to the user based on Images loaded from my online database. Every 10 seconds the image changes, and every 1 second the timer updates displaying how many more seconds the current image will be displayed. Now I want to implement the functionality that when the user presses the ImageView (which fills the whole activity) the picture skips and the next picture to be displayed is loaded into the Image View so that the user doesn't have to wait the full 10 seconds and can see the next picture when he wants to. The problem with this is that the current picture is indicated by the `i` counter inside my for loop. I tried assinging `currphoto = i` however this doesn't work as it requires currphoto to be declared final. I am looking for advice on how to implement this functionality in the best way possible.

```
 public void slideshow(ArrayList<ImageDisplayer> a, final int currImage, final int offset) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picturedisplay);
    int currphoto = 0;

    final long DELAY = 300; // milliseconds
    final long VIEW_TIME = 10000;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final TimerTask update_time = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SlideShow.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView time_rem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_rem);
                    int timeRem = Integer.parseInt(time_rem.getText().toString());
                    timeRem--;
                    time_rem.setText(Integer.toString(timeRem));
                }});
        }};
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask() {
                int i = currImage;
                int off = 0;
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SlideShow.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (i < imageDisplayerArrayList.size()) {
                                TextView time_rem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_rem);
                                time_rem.setText("10");
                                Bitmap myBitmap = ConvertToImage(imageDisplayerArrayList.get(i).getImage());
                                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picturedisplay);
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                Integer.toString(imageDisplayerArrayList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                               .show();
                                i++;
                                off = (int)(Math.rint(Math.ceil((double) i / 10) * 10));
                                if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 10 != 0) {
                                    uploadImage2("2650225",Integer.toString(off),i);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                update_time.cancel();
                            }
                                                             }});
                }},
            DELAY,VIEW_TIME
    );
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(update_time, 0,1000);
```

Comment: where is imageview onClick logic?

Comment: I didn't implement it, I tried implementing it outside of the timertasks however this raises the problem with the final variable.. implementing it inside the timertasks doesn't work because I need to restart them when the next image is loaded, and I can't do this from inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) of [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html)

ViewFlipper will animate between two or more views that have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular interval, so your image slideshow purpose is going to be solved with this.

Android ViewFlipper support auto flip which can be controlled with startFlipping() and stopFlipping() method. We can set the auto flip interval using setFlipInterval(period). Note that the interval period is in milliseconds.

Please refer [Android ViewFlipper Example](http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example) for implementing image slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow three step:

1.First make a function which can only change image.

2.Set timer which can can change every 10 sec. Call first function on timer.

3.set onclick listener and call first function.

Comment: Where do I set the onClickListener tho? Inside the timer or in the onCreate method?

Comment: imagechange()                 timer{ imagechange() }     onClickListener{imagechange()  }